# «Мне захотелось пить» - do I want to have a drink now? Or I wanted to have a drink in the past?

Tags: значения, tense

In "мне захотелось пить" -  should I think that past tense «захотелось» means «A desire to drink **has come** to me, and as a result there's an ongoing state where I want to have a drink **now**»?

Comment: please, don't use uppercase the way you use it in titles

Comment: "I felt a desire to drink", then depending on how long ago are you talking about: if it's a second or a minute ago, you're probably saying that you're thirsty right now, if it's about more distant past - then it's about how you were thirsty in the past.

Answer (score 3):

This is ambiguous, it can function as both Past Simple and Present Perfect.

> *Past Simple* - Когда я наелся вяленой рыбы, мне так захотелось пить, что я выпил литр воды за раз.
>
> *Present Perfect* - Мне захотелось пить, у тебя не найдётся минералочки?

Answer (score 3):

Although it may mean that the desire **has** come or **had** come depending on the context, I won't use the phrase to say I want to drink now.

To make it sound natural in the present perfect sense you have to relax it, make it sound more colloquial, for example:

*Мне что-то захотелось пить.* - I'm kind of thirsty.

Notice that **что-то** is not an object of **пить**, but just a word used to mince the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

In a Past Simple form it's quite common, sort of "I was thirsty".

In a Present Perfect it sounds a bit awkward. A more natural form would be "Мне захотелось *по*пить".